# How to display album with more than one music genre category in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

My query is:

```
SELECT a.title 
FROM   album a, 
       album_genre ag, 
       genre g 
WHERE  a.album_id = ag.album_id 
       AND ag.genre_id = g.genre_id 
       AND Count(ag.album_id) > 1;
```

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Is better use the `inner join` syntaxis the where is already consider obsolete.

```
SELECT a.title 
FROM   album a
INNER JOIN album_genre ag, 
   ON a.album_id = ag.album_id 
INNER JOIN genre g 
   ON ag.genre_id = g.genre_id 
GROUP BY 
       a.title 
HAVING Count(g.genre_id) > 1;
```

**Note:** I'm not sure about how to do the `group by` because dont know about your schema.

I think this simple version could work if `albun_genre` have the duplicated rows.

```
SELECT a.title 
FROM   album a
INNER JOIN album_genre ag, 
   ON a.album_id = ag.album_id     
GROUP BY 
       a.title 
HAVING Count(ag.album_id) > 1;
```